# How can I create a OBD 2 Android application like torqe? Are there any software simulators available or I need a car to test application?

Tags: android, obd-ii

I want to create a OBD 2 android application like Torque. Are there any software simulators available for testing or I need a car with OLM adapter to test the application?
I got to know about the github library https://github.com/pires/android-obd-reader/releases/tag/2.0-RC4 , is there any other library/tool available or I can get all possible data from this?

Comment: I am wondering if any of the answers were helpful?

Answer (score 1):

I did run into a obd II simulator I found in the google app store which I installed on one of my development phones https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.beastovest.obd.simulator

On a second phone I installed the Car Scanner from the store (free) 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ovz.carscanner

The setup is pretty simple. Just pair the device from the simulator to the scanner.

In the simulator I can change engine values and I can see the commands and the changes in the scanner. You can see the rest of the communication as well. The simulator is $5. Very nice for that price.  I can also see the complete communication which I need for my app development. I also speed up the understanding of the ELM327 commands. Here is the spec: https://www.elmelectronics.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/ELM327DS.pdf

Hope that helps anybody.

Comment: nice applications

Comment: Well if you feel that helped you u can upvote the answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a free software simulator with simple GUI, called [OBDSim](https://icculus.org/obdgpslogger/obdsim.html). It works on Windows, Linux and OSX (among others).
There's also a hardware simulator ECUSim 2000, which isn't free and also isn't cheap.

That GitHub repo you linked to is actually an Android application, capable of acquiring OBD data from a car. It is not an OBD library, however it is based on [one](https://github.com/pires/obd-java-api) (by the same developer, pires).

Now to (partially) answer your second question: no, you can't get all the data OBD offers ([PIDs on wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OBD-II_PIDs), but there are more manufacturer specific ones) using this library. However you can get all the interesting data that you'll need if you won't be doing something really specific. I don't know if there are other similar libraries but I found this one well written, well documented and well performing.